# Not able to find one out of multiple nearly identical buttons using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am struggling to refer to these buttons which are identical, except for one thing which is the #text (in this case 'Sportart'). There are no ID's or anything else that might define these buttons reliably.

Here's the code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn--anchor sticky bg-translucent text-uppercase pdgx sm-pdg text-h3 w-100"> Sportart <svg role="img" class="icon icon--arrow-down icon--toggle bg-brand text-white"><use xlink:href="#arrow-down"></use></svg></button>
```

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `xpath` to identify the button.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Sportart')]")
```

or

```
 driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space(.)='Sportart']")
```